# how many columns does TDengine database support?

Tags: tdengine

I think the TDengine database only supports 6 tags, but I want to know about non-tag columns, is there an unlimited number of non-tag columns?

Answer (score 0):

I think you use the 1.6 version of TDengine which only supports a max of 6 tags, but the current version of TDengine (2.4) supports maximum of 128 tags and a total of 4096 columns.